# Holomorphic functions with conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on the same domain $D$. If $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ and $g(z)=u(z)-iv(z)$, and $f(1+i)=2+3i$, then $g(4+3i)=?$ Is it possible to find $g?$

Comment: From the way you have it written, are $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ real?

Comment: Yes, they are real.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic, the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.

For $f$ you know that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

and for $g$ you know that
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

This tells you that $\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \cfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$.

Do the same for $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

What does this tell you about $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Both $u$ and $v$ are constant functions.

Comment: @SucharitaDeb Yes! Since $f(1+i)=2+3i$, $u(z) = \text{___}$ and $v(z) =\text{___}$. And since $g(z) = u(z) - iv(z)$ for all $z \in D$, $g(4+3i) = \text{___}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ are *real*, then $f(z)+g(z)=2u(z)$ is constant by the open mapping theorem, thus $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are both constant (since they couldn't be open maps). Thus $f(z)=2+3i$ for all $z$, so $g(z)=2-3i$ for all $z$.